# splice in javascript change values of my other objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

**NOTE! this is for an extra credit assignment, so I am not looking for code re-write but rather guidance in what I am doing wrong. I have gone through my code several times and I feel like I am just missing something very minor. I have completed it fully with the exception of the following error:**

I created an array of objects. 
Everything starts off fine. I can create objects and they are added to the array and successfully displayed on my screen with correct values.
The trouble arises when I delete an object from the array. It does delete this object and removes it from my displayed list, but suddenly all the remaining objects get new values. These new values match those of the LAST object I added to the array. I need them to retain their original values!

```
var tableContent = document.getElementById("tableContent");
var tableString = " ";
var counter = 0;
var courseArray = [];
tableContent.innerHTML = tableString;

function Course(number, title, hours, prereq) {
    this.number = number;
    this.title = title;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.prereq = prereq;
}

function createCourse() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number-field");
    var title = document.getElementById("title-field");
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours-field");
    var prereq = document.getElementById("prereq-field");
    courseArray.push(new Course(number, title, hours, prereq));
    buildCourseTableBody();
}
function buildCourseTableBody() {

    tableString += "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + counter + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + courseArray[counter].number.value + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + courseArray[counter].title.value + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + courseArray[counter].hours.value + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + courseArray[counter].prereq.value + "</td>" +
        "<td><button id='delete' onClick='deleteCourse(" + counter + ")'><img id=counter src='../image/delete.png' alt='delete course'></button></td>" +
        "</tr>";
    counter++;
    tableContent.innerHTML = tableString;

}
function deleteCourse(counterIndex) {
    courseArray.splice(counterIndex, 1);
    counter--;
    tableString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
        tableString += "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + courseArray[i].number.value + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + courseArray[i].title.value + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + courseArray[i].hours.value + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + courseArray[i].prereq.value + "</td>" +
            "<td><button id='delete' onClick='deleteCourse(" + i + ")'><img id=counter src='../image/delete.png' alt='delete course'></button></td>" +
            "</tr>";
    }
```

and HTML code(everything in main, which is wrapped in body. js file is included):

```
<main id="main-index">
    <h1 id="page-caption">CS Department Course Catalog</h1>


    <div id="course-list">
        <p id="course-list-caption">Course List</p>

        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Hours</th>
                <th>Prereq</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="tableContent">


            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div id="course-edit">
        <p><input id="number-field" placeholder="Course #, e.g. CS234"></p>
        <p><input id="title-field" placeholder="Course title, e.g. Database and Wed Systems Development"></p>
        <p><input id="hours-field" placeholder="Credit hours, e.g. 3.0"></p>
        <p><input id="prereq-field" placeholder="Course prereqs, e.g. CS150, CS111"></p>

        <p><button id="add" onClick="createCourse()">+</button></p>
    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: If you filled your `array` with createCourse, then all elements will have the same value. Log your array with `console.log` and take a look at it in the browser.

Comment: They all have unique and correct values when I first create the array. It is only when I splice an element out that all of the rest obtain the same values, those values being replicates of that which i spliced out.

The create course function is only called when a user clicks the + button. So the values that are used for the new element are correct.
When I splice the array, I go ahead and print out the new array and that is when all the values change.

Comment: add your html codes...let us examine it too

Comment: Okay, as asked I added html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in `createCourse`. You are assigning the `HTML-Elements` instead of their value.

```
function createCourse() {
  var number = document.getElementById("number-field").value;
  var title = document.getElementById("title-field").value;
  var hours = document.getElementById("hours-field").value;
  var prereq = document.getElementById("prereq-field").value;
  courseArray.push(new Course(number, title, hours, prereq));
  buildCourseTableBody();
}
```

The class course will hold a reference to the element itself. Like that your functions which generate the table itself, will always get the most **current** value of the input boxes.

Notice:
Don't forget to adapt `buildCourseTableBody` and `deleteCourse`.

Comment: Again, when I run this everything goes perfectly fine. It is only when I delete a course that errors arise. In fact I just added .value to the object variables and it broke the program from the start.

When I create courses it works. When I delete courses, it deletes the course from the list and then reassigns the remaining courses all the same values that the last course I added had.

Comment: So I see what you are saying about giving the most current values of the input boxes, but that is the case when I  call that function.
When I splice an object from the array I don't understand why it assigns all other objects the most current values again, if createCourse isn't even called there?

Comment: I just typed this into a fiddle. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/h5b7qw5e/
Can you give me an example, that does not work there?

Comment: Here it is with the css and delete image: http://winklerboozen.dx.am/cs234/wk13ec/html/index.html

Comment: But you haven't changed your JS at all. I think you don't get me really.

To your question regarding the references: The app takes the most recent values of the input field, because your array is holding references. References to the HTML elements. So whenever you access the array elements (not calling the functions or so), those references are used to look up the value. Just remove `.value` from all array accesses inside `buildCourseTableBody` and `deleteCourse` and use the `createCourse` function from above (it is modified).

Comment: Yeah I wasnt change my JS because here I thought you were misunderstanding my question. I will try that now, thanks.